# Video e imagen en el mismo card con 2 columnas

Tags: html, bootstrap

Buenas tengo un problema y es el siguiente: Deseo que en una misma card se pueda visualizar un video y una imagen. Es decir que, la card tenga dentro de manera divida la imagen y el video.

La estructura que tengo es la siguiente

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
                <div class="col col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-sm-6">

                            <div class="card h-100 border">
                                <div class="col col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-check form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input class="form-check" id="OpcionD" name="OpcionA" value="" type="radio">
                                        <label class="form-check-label ml-1" for="OpcionD">Respuesta A</label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="embed embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1 mt-1">
                                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="assets/video/2.mp4"
                                            frameborder="0"></iframe>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col col-sm-6">
                                    <img class="w-100" src="assets/images/opcAMate.jpg" alt="Respuesta A">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

y el resultado que me da, es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he podido alinearlos en la card ¿Alguna idea de como alinearlos?
Se me olvido decir, las imágenes y videos están alojados en mi pc, por si no logran visualizarse, perdón.

Comment: Podrías poner dentro del card `<div class="row">` y dentro del row pones las dos columnas

Comment: Gracias. le agregue el row dentro de la card y elimine el card body y con eso quedo. Aunque se me hace raro porque cuando tenia el card-body y agreguaba el row seguia con el mismo comportamiiento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la [documentación de bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/) tienes el ejemplo perfecto para crear una card. Basta con que agregues una row con dos columnas e insertes el contenido.

A continuación te dejo el enlace a [este snippet](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GFPI7JQXOIRN) en el cual podrás ver el resultado.

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo, con ello quedo mas claro y pude acomodar mis items.